# Identify string value in jSON based on FieldName only with array index changes every time

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, postman, postman-testcase

How to search whole jSON output from postman and get only string values from newFields array and save in variable based on fieldName only

> fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost

Have to update Test case everytime since array index changes for newField with new build, next time the fieldid index would be /118 or /129 /234 .. so on

**What does not change is fieldName: it remains same**

```
[
  {
   "Fieldid": "Fieldid/112",
    "fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost",
    "stringval": "jklah-dw-4c8d-8320-das313s3ASsda|000725N8WuUrfwAS7alP|banker_name"
  }
]
```

My current postman test is limited to field id only and saving it to variable.

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Stdid", jsonData.newFields[112].stringValue)
```

Comment: what will cahnge ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What should be the result for the situation from your question?

Comment: Fieldid": "Fieldid/112 is only value changes, and the bankern_name in stringval (as mentioned)  fieldid would be /118 or /129 /234 .. so on

Comment: jsonData.newFields[112].stringvalue , so whats the issue with this lcoator?

Comment: @PDHide @ pavelsaman : no issue with locater, it works well. but my question was related to located gets changes every time from newFields[112], newFields[128] so on.. how to save string value only based on fieldName which remains constant in whole JSON

Comment: see the added answer it does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pm.environment.set("stdid",jsonData.newFields.filter((a)=>a.fieldName==="TX.Sessionval.cost")[0].stringval)
```

use filter method of javascrpt array

Comment: thanks, what does [0] signifies, let me try this and update

Comment: the filter returns an array , as the "fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost", is unique it will return an array of 1 element , we are getting taht element back as [0]

Comment: it works for filtering thanks, how to save that string value only into variable

Comment: pm.environment.set("stdid" saves it to variable you can use the code as it is , this is the new way to store envirnment variables

Comment: when print "stdid" it shows  ` "Fieldid": "Fieldid/112",
    "fieldName": "TX.Sessionval.cost",
    "stringval": "jklah-dw-4c8d-8320-das313s3ASsda|000725N8WuUrfwAS7alP|banker_name" `  Looking to save the stringval only

Comment: "stringval": "jklah-dw-4c8d-8320-das313s3ASsda|000725N8WuUrfwAS7alP|banker_name"

Comment: lol i thought it was more complex... clean and easy, any other way around ?

Comment: this is the cleanest option

Comment: was my question okay in 1st place ? or do i need to update

Comment: could you upvote also , you can edit question to make this infomation like the arry index was changing and all

Comment: any idea if this has to be filter the same in groovy script?